# Example of a nonincreasing function $f(x): [0, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$ such that $\lim_{x \to \infty}xf(x) = 0$, but $\int_0^{\infty} f(x) = \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, improper-integrals

Is there a nonincreasing function $f(x): [0, \infty) \to [0, \infty) $ such that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty}xf(x) = 0$, but $\int_0^{\infty} f(x) = \infty$?

I think I tried every 'tradictional function'. However, I have noticed that there is no requirement for the function to be continuous - maybe that's a hint.

Comment: I assume you mean $[0,\infty)$ instead of $[0,\infty]$ for the domain. How about something like $1/(x\log(x))$? (Suitably modified for small $x$ so the function is defined at zero and nonincreasing on $[0,\infty)$.)

Comment: Wait a minute please, I will check it

Comment: Yeah, I think it works. I don't know why I didn't think of multiplications of basic functions when basic functions did not fit the criteria. Thank you sir.

Comment: You'll have to modify the function for $x < 1 + \epsilon$ because $\log(x)$ is negative for $x < 1$ and zero at $x=1$. But the tail of the function has the property you desire.

Comment: @OliverDiaz That's not defined at $0.$

Comment: @OliverDiaz Can $1/x^2$ be extended to a nondecreasing function defined at $x=0$, while still integrating to $\infty$? (But the question originally had $[0,\infty]$ for the codomain, so $1/x^2$ would qualify if you define it as $+\infty$ at $x=0$.)

Comment: @OliverDiaz that doesn't work for integral condition.

Comment: @mathbb It does, because of the "wide" vertical singularity near $x=0$. The tail has finite integral, though.

Comment: @Bungo I think I could just modify your function for x = 0 and x = 1 to get full function. Isn't that right?

Comment: You need the function to be nonnegative, but $1/(x\log(x))$ is negative for $0<x<1$.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I forgot about the nonnegative condition.

Comment: But wouldn't it be easier to simply take 1/((x+1)log(x+1))? If needed it can be written that I cut off the part for x < 0.

Comment: As suggested by @Bungo, let $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{\log(x)}$ for $x\geq e$, for $0\leq x<e$ one can define $f$ linearly so the $f(0)>f(e)=\frac{1}{e}$